# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics was unintentionally added to nupkg dependencies

Tags: roslyn, metrics

I added a NuGet packages 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics' (v2.9.8) to my project to measure code metrics.
Just I wanted to measure code metrics, I don't mean to write any code depends the library.

Then I created nupkg with nuspec below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
<!--
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
-->
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release of this library.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2018 My Company.</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.2" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Next I created with a command `NuGet.exe pack MyCompany.MyProject.csproj`, and a nupkg generated.
After that I checked the nupec included in the generated nupkg.

The nuspec is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyCompany.MyProject</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>MyCompany.MyProject</title>
    <authors>My Company.</authors>
    <owners>My Company.</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>MyCompany.MyProject is a example.</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release of this library.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2018 My Company.</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics" version="2.9.8" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

There was a dependency to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics unintentionally.

I also added a NuGet package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers' as well, but it wouldn't apprear in the generated nuspec. I don't know the difference.

I would like to avoid to be added any dependency libraries to nupkg dependencies, except libraries which my project depends on.

How can I make it as I intend.

Is it a problem of the 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics'? Should I report to the developers?

Comment: Can you show the PackageReference from your project where you added Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics.

Comment: Hi @PauloMorgado, it wouldn't be showed anywhere, in the package references, and also analyzers.

Comment: It must be in your csproj file or any other project referenced by it.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what I am saying.
Even though there was not any references of 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics' in our project, but a dependency entry for 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Metrics' was generated in nuspec included in nupkg, by nuget package creation command specifying my project. it is a result which I don't want.